# Are there muscle workouts that warm up other muscles?

Tags: warm-up

In looking for ways to reduce warm-up time, I got to wondering if there are exercises that could serve as a warm-up for other exercises. For example, shoulder press recruits triceps as a secondary muscle, so could shoulder press serve as a warm-up for tricep extensions? If this is the case, you could theoretically cut your warm-up time in half by using exercises in your first series as a warm-up for exercises in your second series and so on and so forth.

Comment: What does your warm up currently look like / what muscle groups are you working? The S&S warm up is literally 3 moves. I've been in scenarios where we'd use animal flow to get everything going quickly as well